# GIt server or Local Machine

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

Just started learning Dev-ops through an Training institute , so they are teaching GIT as a local server(EC2 Machine) where git is installed and each developer have their own branch created in it ,and when developer are done with their coding in the LOCAL machine they move it to the server and add it to their branch and synced with the remote repo(Github). They inform its done this way so code is not lost when PC dies.

is this how its done, everything i read on this contradicts this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each starts from their own local repo, what you do is add the *common* repo where the work of all students will be held as a *remote* and then you push your branch into a branch of the remote.... it doesn't matter that the branches do not start from the same root commit.... a repo can hold many commits, many of them can have no parents (a.k.a **root commits**) and then branches can point to the *tips commits*.

So.... suppose you have 2 developers.... each with their own brach:

Dev 1:

```
* CCC (master) third commit
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit
```

Dev 2:

```
* FFF (master) third commit for something else
* EEE second commit for something else
* DDD first commit for a different thing
```

Then, each developer will push into a *separate* branch. So developer 1, will do:

```
git remote add some-remote url-to-remote
git fetch some-remote
git push some-remote master:dev1-branch
```

When that happens, in the common remote you will have:

```
* CCC (dev1-branch) third commit
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit
```

And developer1 will see:

```
* CCC (master, some-remote/dev1-branch) third commit
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit
```

Then developer 2 does something like that:

```
git remote add blah-remote url-to-remote
git fetch blah-remote
git push blah-remote master:dev2-branch
```

Then in the common repo you would have:

```
* CCC (dev1-branch) third commit
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit

* FFF (dev2-branch) third commit for something else
* EEE second commit for something else
* DDD first commit for a different thing
```

I am separating the branches there to make it *clear* that they are *really* separate.... if you try to check with `git log --oneline` I do not think there will be a separation in the chart.... though there should be one.

Developer 2 would see:

```
* CCC (blah-remote/dev1-branch) third commit
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit

* FFF (master, blah-remote/dev2-branch) third commit for something else
* EEE second commit for something else
* DDD first commit for a different thing
```

And developer 1, can run a `git fetch some-remote` to see the branch pushed by developer 2 and would see:

```
* CCC (master, some-remote/dev1-branch) third commit
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit

* FFF (some-remote/dev2-branch) third commit for something else
* EEE second commit for something else
* DDD first commit for a different thing
```